# How to send request using ajax in every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i want to send request  in to my php file  in every x seconds  using ajax  how can i achieve this

Here is my ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun()
{
var exam=new XMLHttpRequest();
exam.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(exam.readyState==4)  
    {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=exam.responseText;
    }
}
exam.open("GET","rat_test.php?name=pramod",true);
exam.send(null);
}
</script>
```

How can i get my goal

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Just set up a JavaScript timer to trigger every x seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval()

In the below example, `5000` represents 5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun() {
        var exam=new XMLHttpRequest();
        exam.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if(exam.readyState==4) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=exam.responseText;
            }
        }
        exam.open("GET","rat_test.php?name=pramod",true);
        exam.send(null);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        fun();
    },5000);
</script>
```

Resources:

[setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
setInterval(function(){
    //your code here
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 5; // Seconds
setInterval(fun, x * 1000);
```

The above code would run the fun function every 5 seconds. The reason we times x by 1000 is because it takes it as milliseconds.

So 1000 = 1 second, 2000 = 2 seconds and so on...

Comment: That would be true if we were calling it, we are not.

Comment: try  it here if you want :http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jtgvqk8q/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Jquery function :

```
//x in second 
var sec=x

setInterval(function(){fun()}, x*1000);
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval function

```
var x = setInterval(function(){
  //Your code
},200); //miliseconds to interval
```

and if you want to stop it

```
clearInterval(x);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp